# How to call Html.RenderAction() with parameters declarated in jscript?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript in *.cshtml file

```
$(function () {

sliderDiv.slider({
  range: true,
  min: minVal,
  max: maxVal,
  values: [minVal, maxVal]
});

sliderDiv.bind("slidechange", function (event, ui) {

  var d = "min=" + ui.values[0] + "&max=" + ui.values[1];
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("Update", "Default")',
    data: d,
    success: function (result, ajaxObj) {
        alert('ok');
        alert(result.min + " - " + result.max);
        $("#ajaxresult").html('@{Html.RenderAction("Update", "Default");}');
    },
   error: function (ajaxObj, message, exceptionObj) { alert('no'); }
});
});
}
```

And Controller:

```
public ActionResult Update(int? min, int? max)
        {
            if(min == null) min = 1;
            if(max == null) max = 1;
            var s = new SliderModel()
                                {
                                    min = (int)min * 1000,
                                    max = (int)max * 1000
                                };

            return new JsonResult
                       {
                           Data = s,
                           ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                           JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                           ContentType = "json"
                       };

        }
```

I want to use this line

```
$("#ajaxresult").html('@{Html.RenderAction("Update", "Default");}');
```

to send `ui.values[0]` and `ui.values[1]` as `min` and `max` parameters to `Html.RenderAction("Update", "Default")`

Something like `$("#ajaxresult").html('@{Html.RenderAction("Update", "Default", new {min = ui.values[0], max = ui.values[1]});}');`

How can I do something like that???

Comment: Hey Dima, did you try my answer? did it work?

Comment: Yes, I've just tried. Thanks, it works...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Update", "Default")';
url += '/?min=' + ui.values[0] + '&max=' + ui.values[1];
$("#ajaxresult").load(url);
```

[**`load` docs**](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.