# render the same MVC4 partial view from Jquery but use different controller methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, controller, partial-views

I have 3 html anchor tags.

depending on what link is clicked, i want to render the same view, but pointing to a different  controller action.

How would i render the partial view and point the view to a different action on the same controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RenderAction()`.

```
 @Html.RenderAction("Details", "User", new {id = Model.Id})
```

[Some help](http://captaincodeman.com/2009/02/21/when-to-use-renderaction-vs-renderpartial-with-asp-net-mvc/) about how to render partial views.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810598/the-difference-between-html-action-and-html-renderaction) on StackOverflow explains the difference between `Html.Action` and `Html.RenderAction`, that may interest you.

**UPDATE:**

For doing this in JavaScript I redirect you to this question: [How to call `Html.RenderAction()` with parameters declarated in jscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897433/how-to-call-html-renderaction-with-parameters-declarated-in-jscript)

Comment: thank you. would you mind expanding your example to replace a div's contents with the renderaction in a piece of javascript code?

Comment: Look at my updated answer, I think this is exactly what you are looking for.